# Axis Marshaller

Tags: java, marshalling, axis, wsdl2java, unmarshalling

I have a group of classes that were created using wsdl2java (Axis 1.4) and am looking for a way to unmarshal and marshal the data from/to String and Object.  I have written a JAXB unmarshaller that works well for some of our newer internal objects  since we used xjc to create the classes but do not have time to convert the old axis classes and need to find a marshal/unmarshal solution for the code as-is.

Can somebody please point me in a direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did find an answer to my own question so thought was worth posting.

Found a decent link that outlines the process with Axis: http://bwithers.wordpress.com/2006/07/29/serializing-an-axis-javabean-object-to-xml/

I still prefer JAXB over Axis but this will do.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that there's also a unmarshaller utility in [one of the comments](http://bwithers.wordpress.com/2006/07/29/serializing-an-axis-javabean-object-to-xml/#comment-3246) in that link. This has been extremely helpful, thank you @cmutt78.